Learn Mamdani-type Fuzzy-Inference-System model
I have a problem understanding how learning Mamdani-type FIS works. The introduction to FIS on the MatLab Youtube channel states, that FIS (they show Mamdani-typed) both work with or without machine learning. You either learn from data or you need a domain expert to define rules. But how does learning the rules and Membership Functions work if you only have a limited amount of rules.
Sugeno-typed FIS are pretty easy to learn since you can use the cartesian product of all invar-sets and define/learn a unique function with it's own coefficients for every rule. The prediction/classification/... task uses all functions since it aggregates the results of all functions (for example using weighted-sum)
But Mamdani-typed rules map to a fuzzy outvar set. In all examples I saw you had one rule per set. But considering the usually pretty small amount of sets (for example LOW, MED, HIGH) you can't use every combination of rules like Sugeno-typed FIS do.
So how does learning the correct rules and the MFs for the outvars work?
